# ASP.NET force user to IE as default

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, browser

I have a web app built in asp.net/vb. The scripts on the site only work properly with IE. Is there a way to force the user to use IE all of the time on the site?

Comment: Bad approach, You can't restrict your users to use IE only.

Comment: Which script? client side or server side. If it's server side then browser dosen't matter.

Answer (score 2):

You should not. Are you really willing to ignore 75% of the traffic? or are you paid by microsoft and have got a really cool website idea? Any ways, you can do that by using javascript and detecting the browser and if its not IE then do not show anything(Make you main div `"display:none"`). Here is an example http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp to detect browser. Yet again these approaches are used for customizing styling for browsers and not for what you want it to.

```
function detectIE()
{
   var isIE=navigator.userAgent.toString().indexOf("IE") != -1
   if(isIE)
   {
      document.getElementById("main").style.display="block";
   }
   else
   alert("This website can only be accessed using Internet Explorer");
}
<body onload="detectIE">
<div id="main" style="display:none;">
//Everything inside this div
</div>
</body>
```

Another approach is by using conditionals

```
<!--[if gte IE 6]>
<div id="main" style="display:none;">
    //Everything inside this div
    </div>
<![endif]-->
```

Remember, it's not a 100% solution, browsers can change there user agent strings and present themselves as IE or javascript can be turned off. You should consider adding support for other browsers rather than ignoring them completely.